# ¿como crear un buscador que pueda consultar distintas columnas?

Tags: javascript, html

tengo una duda
por ejemplo tengo un

```
<input type="text" id="busqueda">
```

y en mi base de datos tengo las columnas  id, nombre, apellido, correo, telefono

pudiera con un solo input realizar una busqueda? por ejemplo si escribo un nombre por ejemplo pedro, me busque en la columna de nombre, o si escribo un correo, pueda validar si el input contiene un @ o si es numero de telefono poder validar si lo que se ingresa en el input son numeros, algo asi

Comment: Hola, tu pregunta esta sumamente incompleta, a donde quieres buscar? ¿en una tabla? en un backend  como php, c# u otro?, ¿dónde? ¿que intentaste?

Comment: bueno opino lo mismo que @JuanSalvadorPortugal, y para lo que comentas de validacion de @ y numeros puedes usar los siguientes tipos de type: mail, number

Comment: Puedes utilizar el operador LIke de MySQL, te dejo un link para que le des una vista y lo puedas implementar https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html Y otro con algunos ejemplos http://cristobalgonzalez.com/blog/index.php/busquedas-en-mysql-like-y-full-text-search/

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal si en una tabla de base de datos, el buscador ya lo tengo pero solo busca en la columna nombre y me lo despliega en un datatable jquery pero la pregunta mas que nada seria si en ese mismo input se puede buscar en varias columnas de la tabla de mi base de datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función **substr_count** de **PHP** para identificar si es un **correo** al buscar el arroba.

```
if (substr_count($busqueda, '@') == 1) {
   $Query = "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE correo = '$busqueda'";
} else {
   $Query = "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE 
   id LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR 
   nombre LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR
   apellido LIKE '%$busqueda%' OR
   telefono LIKE '%$busqueda%'";
}

$Result = DB::Connect($Query);
```

> Es sólo un ejemplo condicionando la búsqueda por correo al identificar
>   el arroba, puedes hacer lo mismo con los demás campos, cómo
>   identificar si es tipo entero el dato a buscar, sí es así podríamos
>   saber qué se trata del id o el teléfono según su longitud, así lo
>   podrias hacer con cada campo o bien agregarle LIKE por cada columna.

Comment: en dado caso de que escriba nombre y apellido seria algo que no se pudiera buscar?

Comment: Si escriben el nombre y apellido no entraría en la condición del correo, pero si funcionaría, ya que tienes la búsqueda por nombre y apellido en el entonces.

Comment: bueno gracias me sirvió concatene nombre y apellido y pude buscarlo en ambas

Answer (score 0):

podrias usar expresiones regulares para ver que tipo de dato tienes en tu input. Supongamos que quieres validar por 3 tipos de datos: nombre(string) nro de telefono(numerico) o email. Para esos 3 podrias hacer algo asi:

Suponiendo que en la variable $input tengas el value de tu input

```
 if (/^([0-9])*$/.test($input)){
   funcionBuscarPorNumero($input) //llamas a una funcion que busque por numero
 } else if (/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+).\w+$/.test($input)) {
   funcionBuscarPorEmail($input) //llamas a funcion que busque por email
 } else {
   funcionBuscarPorNombre($input)} //llamas a funcion que busque por nombre
```